# Is there a way in C++ to implement Coroutines that apply to multiple levels of function calls?

Tags: c++

I wish to implement a way in C++ to be able to midway through a function cease execution within the function and return up some number of function calls. For example, I might have a function F and I want this code to return all the way up to F without having to have any special code within F or the functions F calls other than the one performing this return. I then want to be able to at some point execute a piece of code that resumes all execution within the original location. I imagine this can be done via stack manipulation but I have no idea if there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: Which language are you using? C and C++ have different kinds of stuff on the stack and are substantially different languages.

Comment: You can't be using both. They're not the same language. You might be coding one part of the application in one language and another part in the other, but you can't be using both at the same time. Any answer for one language may not be applicable to the other. You need to pick one.

Comment: Just an FYI, intensive purposes -> intents and purposes, no offense meant, it made me smile

Comment: @user64742 So it seems, although this [site](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/usage-for-all-intensive-purposes-intents) says the former is a mistake based on a mishearing, which is what I assumed in the first place.

Comment: @user64742 I think Nicol is just saying that you need to pick the language in which the solution will be implemented, not that you need to change the whole application.

Comment: you could use inline assembly

Comment: wait are you in gnu gcc codeblocks?

Comment: because Microsoft's assembly inline is different than gcc

Comment: in microsoft it's more like this:

__asm{};

and for gcc it's more like this:

asm();

Comment: pass a libfunctionexecutor of some sort to the dll so that the dll calls back to the application whenever needed?

Comment: Do you control the "another executable", or only the dll?

Comment: It is relevant if it means you *don't have to* mess with the stack

Comment: presumably that program is written in something that knows how dlls work. I would expect you can write a dll around the "library functions" that you will use and have your C++ dll bind to that.

Comment: Have the C++ dll link to library dll. You'll need a header full of `declspec(dllimport)` functions

Comment: I did. When I said "do you control the executable?", I meant "can you make code changes to it, such as extracting this library to a dll, and linking that in both the C++ dll and the exe?"

Comment: You are going to need to look up how to write a dll in the language you executable uses. It will involve declaring which functions the dll exports somewhere. E.g. in C++ that's added to the function declaration, e.g. `declspec(dllexport) void foo()`.

Answer (score 2):

Given that we're dealing with DLL's, it's pretty safe to say that we're dealing with Windows. Windows has no real notion of "exiting" a DLL "back" to the executable. Windows  does have an idea how standard function calls work (`WINAPI`), but doesn't even require that the functions from `GetProcAddress` are `WINAPI` calls. And that's just about the functions on external interfaces, `inline` functions don't need to obey the rules for `GetProcAddress`. In fact, Windows doesn't really require your code to be built from functions at all. A Finite State Compiler may emit code which uses jumps instead of calls.

So, the challenge here is that your executable has an arbitrary ABI, GCC has its own ABI, and the two are entirely incompatible. You figures out that much when you implemented your own "queue" mechanism. There's no generic mechanism possible.

Comment: @user64742: GCC is a traditional compiler for procedural languages, and indeed uses call stacks. But I don't see what you gain by cutting the top of a stack. You seem to miss the fundamental part of a stack: you can put stuff on top, without caring what's below. The whole "fake return" part you suggest won't work with dtors and exceptions. Besides, if you did want an empty stack, the far easier way would be to create a new thread.

Comment: @user64742: The problem is that we already have a model for "B stops doing its work, all state of B is retained, and A starts doing work". That model is "B calls A". This is so fundamental that it keeps being true even if A or B are the more exotic models like Finite State Machines. Doesn't mean B calls one of those 1000 functions in A directly, but it definitely means you don't play silly stack games. You call A on top of the B stack.